# Subscribe to a child array of the collection document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection which represents the uploaded files for the user with a structure like so:

```
{
  _id : SKHdspjhs92346
   files : [ { file_name : "1.txt" , file_path : "/home/test1"/} , { file_name : "2.txt" , file_path : "/home/test2"/}  ]
}
```

I want to subscribe to this collection array changings.

So when client uploads a file im doing a push :

```
 AttachmentsList.update({_id : id},
                           { $push: { files :  {file_name : fileName, file_path: filePath}}});
```

And a pull when deleted:

```
AttachmentsList.update( {"_id": id }, {"$pull": { "files" : {file_name : fileName,file_path: filePath} } } );
```

I want the elements dinamically change in template. Is it possible to do so? Currently i have this publisher

```
  Meteor.publish("attachments_list_limited", function (count,id) {


        var test =  AttachmentsList.find({_id : id}, { "files.$": 1 },{limit: count}, {sort: {"files.file_name": -1}});

        console.log("changed, gout elements: " + test.count());
        return test;

    });
```

But it doesnt work reactively like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish to try to make your publish reactive to the user structure's updates through #autorun.